# HTML CSS JS Issue when the keyboard slides up in mobile screens

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, web-frontend

I made this https://utkarshbhimte.github.io/DevMash-backup/ using scrollify. 
The bug I am facing is When the select field is tapped and keyboard slides up which causes the screen to scroll back a section. This is my Code https://github.com/Utkarshbhimte/DevMash-backup

Answer (score 0):

You could try using [fullPage](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/) instead of Scrollify. fullPage let's you add sections where you want normal scrolling behaviour:

https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js

Comment: I don't think scrollify is causing this. coz I have coded it to disable scrollify once the user gets to the registration form.

Comment: I just looked at the api for scrollify properly, and looked at your code. There is a standardScrollElements option, but you've got it set to ".dropdown-content" only. Have you tried adding "#form"to the standardScrollElements? I think you'd have to set the height for the #form element manually then.